# OnClick Event not invoking on IMG Tag

Tags: c#, image

I have a label whose id is lblppb and have assigned an IMG tag as a string as below:

```
lblppb.Text = "<a href='//media.mercola.com/themes/mercola/images/view-all-health-topics.jpg' target='_blank' id='BannerLink1'><img alt='Banner' src='../Desert.jpg' height='250' width='300'onclick='alert('Hello..!!')'></a>";
```

This label is in div and it is showing the specified image from src, but when i click on that image i want to generate an alert...

HELP..!
THanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seems to be no space between the image width and the onlick event call
`width='300'onclick='alert('Hello..!!')'`. You have to space them as per below and then try it again.

```
width='300' onclick='alert('Hello..!!')'
```

Alternatively, since your are curious in displaying pop alert message. the the code below should get you going

```
<html><head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function validate()
{
  alert( "Please provide your Profile Picture!" );
return( true );
}
</script>

</head><body>



lblppb.Text = "<a href='//media.mercola.com/themes/mercola/images/view-all-health-topics.jpg' target='_blank' id='BannerLink1'>
<img alt='Banner' src='../Desert.jpg' height='250' width='300' onclick="return(validate());"></a>";

</body></html>
```

Give me a shout if you still need further help. Sectona...

Comment: I think having no space between width and onclick have nothing to do with not showing the alert. Giving space is just for readability  of code in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I always prefer to use external script rather using static inline scripts. Inline scripts are less maintainable and in case of testing it becomes worst. But when you switch to external script it gives you the reliability to have your code in a separate module that is much more testable.

If you have option to modify your ***img*** tag I would surely tell you to do as follows :

Add *id* attribute in your *img* and keep everything same. I have named it(*id*) ***bannerImg***

```
lblppb.Text = "<a href='http://www.hdwallpapers-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cartoon-6.jpg' target='_blank' id='BannerLink1'><img alt='Banner' id='bannerImg' src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WsZ4Q7Y156A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABM/vN1-gy0xZQU/photo.jpg' height='250' width='300'></a>";
```

Now add the following script in your page's head section or any external .js file,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bannerImg").click(function () {
            alert("Hello..!!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

***Note :*** Remember you must include jQuery before using the script.

Or,

when onclick event is fired, call a function and get your stuff done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertMe() {
        alert("Hello....!!!!");
    }
</script>


lblppb.Text = "<a href='http://www.hdwallpapers-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cartoon-6.jpg' target='_blank' id='BannerLink1'><img alt='Banner' id='bannerImg' src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WsZ4Q7Y156A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABM/vN1-gy0xZQU/photo.jpg' height='250' width='800' onclick='alertMe();'></a>";
```

Comment: @ashad...i dont want to use JQuery i want it on Onclick event

Comment: then onclick call a function that will alert you. Try the updated answer.